# iOS Landscape and Portrait Delegate Confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate, landscape-portrait

For the most part I have things well figured out. I can't seem to wrap my head around one small issue. I will outline this issue as best as possible, I don't think at this time posing my question requires me to post any code, but feel free to ask.

My application defaults in Portrait viewing, as most do. In the main interaction area, when the user rotates the device, I don't have to provide code that alters anything major because instead, I place a new view on top of the view stack. This works great and is one of two ways the user can interact with the device in landscape mode.

The second is with a modally presented screen (from this main interaction area) that plays YouTube videos from within the app with a UIWebView, again this works well.

The problem arises when the user dismisses the modal view controller in Landscape mode. What happens is that the user returns to the main interaction area with the content adjusted for landscape mode, and the delegate method normally called from the view controller for this main interaction area is not called, I use this delegate method to make the landscape change normally:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration { }
```

I will include screenshots of exactly what is happening.

[image: The main interaction area]

*A screenshot of the main interaction area in Portrait Mode.*

[image: landscape mode]

*A screenshot of the main interaction area when in Landscape Mode.*

[image: landscape mode upon return from modal]

*A screenshot of the main interaction area after dismissing the modal view controller in Landscape mode and back to the main interaction area (notice the content has centered itself and has cut off the top portion and does not stretch (not that i'm asking it to do that)*

Ideally in this situation, I would like to return to the main screen from Landscape mode and have screenshot 2 be what the user sees and not screenshot 3.

Any suggestions? Again, i'm glad to post code. Thanks in advance.

*edit*

ANSWER:

So simple, I took the code that places the Landscape view on top of the view stack when turned within it's own method. Then I call that method in both the delegate method it previously rested and also in ViewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system only sends `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to a view controller if that view controller controls the top-level view on the screen.  Since you're presenting a modal view controller, the modal view controller gets `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, and your (hidden) view controller doesn't.

The system sends `viewWillAppear:` to a view controller when the view controller's view is about to reappear because a modal view controller is disappearing.  So you should implement `viewWillAppear:`.  In that method, check whether the interface is in landscape orientation.  If it is, show your landscape view.  Otherwise, hide your landscape view.

Comment: Or make a delegate method in the modal view controller to rotate the hidden controller when willRotatejfjtdtdhtdhmgc is called

Comment: There is no reason to rotate a hidden controller's view unless you know the view is about to appear.  Do it in `viewDidAppear:` or some other method (like `layoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`), which the system calls when it's guaranteed that the view will be shown.

Comment: Taking out what I had in that delegate method, putting it in it's own method and calling that method in both the delegate and in viewWillAppear worked. The solution was so simple, thank you :)